# How to test the ngrx store.select of an Observable, in angular5?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, code-coverage, ngrx, ngrx-store

I would like to understand what is missing in the test to cover the file I'm working at, in order to achieve 100% coverage.
Here are the parts under attention:

Given this typescript file:

```
constructor(
  public store: Store<AppState>
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.search$ = this.store.select(s => s.search);
}
```

And this test:

```
it('should start observing the search store', () => {
  const search: any = {
    data: {}
  };
  const state = Observable.of(search);

  const store = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['select']);
  store.select.and.returnValue(state);
  component.store = store;

  component.ngOnInit();

  expect(component.search$).toBe(state);
});
```

Current test coverage:

[image]

I guess what I'm missing is something very stupid I blindly do not see it. Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: It's not covered since its anonymous function unreachable in your test.

Comment: Since the select happens async it doesn't call the anonymous handler you supplied immediately, it would ordinarily execute when an action caused your reducers to process.  You could take the anonymous function out and make it public so you can call it directly and test it without having the regular reducers run to update the store.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indeed as @shaunhusain suggested, this was the fix for the file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fetch();
  this.search$ = this.store.select(this.getStoreSearchData);
}

private getStoreSearchData(store: AppState): Search {
  return store.search;
}
```

and its test:

```
describe('#getStoreSearchData', () => {
  it('should return the search store', () => {
    const search: any = {
      data: {}
    };

    const store = <AppState>{search: search};

    const storeSearch = component['getStoreSearchData'](store);

    expect(storeSearch).toEqual(search);
  });
});
```

and now coverage is back to 100%

Comment: This one works, but it is not a good way to write UTs. You shouldn't test private things using [] accessor. This is kinda hacky and ugly solution. Instead, you should mock store.search, dispatch an action that will update the store and will trigger the selector, and check if search was called.